# Using timer to send textbox lines to notepad

Tags: .net, vb.net, timer, vb.net-2010, notepad

I am VB noobie and coding a small exercise using timer.

After many attempts I could not make it work. I need to send each line of the RichTextBox (`txtcontent`) to the opening notepad.

I set the timer interval at 1000ms (1s), count the textbox lines, and send it (first I try using messagebox). However, everytime the msgbox shows just one first line and keeps repeating. Please correct me. ~Below is my timer code:

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Static j As Integer = 0 
        Dim lineCount As Integer = txtcontent.Lines.Length 
        If j <= lineCount - 1 Then
                    MsgBox(txtcontent.Lines(j)) 'textbox line
        End If
        j += 1
    End Sub
```

Comment: What is txtContent? A TextBox element? And what exactly are you trying to do? Each time the timer ticks should it send all the textbox text to notepad?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted as it seems like a very valid question to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue you are having is the fact that the timer keeps firing before you have clicked on your message box, i.e. There is a re-entrancy issue.

If you disable the timer when you go into the sub routine and enable it at the end you will see that it does indeed cycle through the lines:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    Static j As Integer = 0
    Dim lineCount As Integer = txtContent.Lines.Length
    If j <= lineCount - 1 Then
        MsgBox(txtContent.Lines(j)) 'textbox line
    End If
    j += 1
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Sending each line to Notepad is a bit more involved. Although Notepad in theory does support StandardInput there are issues getting it to work, so SendKeys can be used instead:

```
Private _notePadProcess As Process = Nothing

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    Static j As Integer = 0

    Dim lineCount As Integer = txtContent.Lines.Length
    If j <= lineCount - 1 Then
        WriteLineToNotePad(txtContent.Lines(j))
    End If
    j += 1
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Private Shared Function SetForegroundWindow(hWnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

Private Sub WriteLineToNotePad(line As String)
    If _notePadProcess Is Nothing OrElse _notePadProcess.HasExited OrElse _notePadProcess.MainWindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero Then
        Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe")
        _notePadProcess = Process.Start(startInfo)
        Do Until _notePadProcess.MainWindowHandle <> IntPtr.Zero
            'wait
        Loop
    End If
    SetForegroundWindow(_notePadProcess.MainWindowHandle)
    SendKeys.Send(line + vbCr)
End Sub
```

Comment: It works like charm. I tried the first part of your code and it works. Thank you Matt. (For the second part, I have not studied yet ^^).